# создание массива на jquery

Tags: jquery, php

Не могу понять, как сделать, что бы id элементов, загруженные на страницу, передавались ajax-ом на обработку. На jquery не могу собрать массив этих элементов.
В инете самое интересное нашёл:

```
var arr = array($('ul li').attr('id'));
```

На выходе массив должен иметь вид: `1,2,3,56,81,5`

Такая строчка необходима, что бы на стороне сервера сделать sql запрос с помощью

```
WHERE id IN ('.$arr.')
```

пробовал и так: `<li name="arr['.$row['id'].']">`

но jquery выводит только первый элемент и с квадратными скобками:

```
alert($('ul li').attr('name'));
```

Comment: Добрый день. Вы объясните пожалуйста, что вы хотите в итоге. Ваше решение считаю не верным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Циклы тут не нужны.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="1">List 1</li>
    <li id="2">List 2</li>
    <li id="3">List 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var arrList = $('#list li').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
alert(arrList);
```

[Смотреть пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/aLWrs/)

Comment: Denios, благодарю Вас. Всё работает. Из сил уже выбился.

Comment: @Deonis, а в `map` цикла нет что ли?)

Comment: @Sh4dow, я имел в виду, что писать свои циклы смысла нет. Мы же не будем мучаться, если, к примеру, на PHP нам надо отсортировать массив, а просто используем функцию **sort()**

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = new Array();
var i = 0;
$('li').each(function() {
    arr[i] = $(this).attr('id');
    i++;
});
```

а так если...

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще попробовать на `pure-js` + jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li id="p1">1</li>
<li id="p2">2</li>
<li id="p3">3</li>
<li id="p4">4</li>
<li id="p5">5</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
var newarr = new Array(); // массив id`шников
arr = $('ul > li');       // другой массив DOM объектов
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
newarr.push($(arr[i]).attr("id"));
alert(newarr.length);     // "5"
</script>
```